# Jquery $.each selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, prototypejs, each

I would like to know what `$.each()` stands for in jquery,
What is it selecting?

Is there an equivalent in prototype?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$.each()` isn't selecting anything. It is just a utility to iterate over a collection.

When you do:

```
$('someSelector').each(function() {
    // do something
});
```

jQuery is internally calling:

```
jQuery.each( this, callback, args );
```

...with `this` representing the matched set.

http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L231

You could just as easily call it yourself manually.

```
jQuery.each( $('someSelector'), function() {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you should rather look at

[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

From the documentation

> **The $.each() function is not the same as .each(),** which is used to
>   iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery
>   object. The $.each() function can be
>   used to iterate over any collection,
>   whether it is a map (JavaScript
>   object) or an array. In the case of an
>   array, the callback is passed an array
>   index and a corresponding array value
>   each time. (The value can also be
>   accessed through the this keyword.)

Answer (score 4):

jQuery uses `each` in two ways:

> The .each() method is designed to make
>   DOM looping constructs concise and
>   less error-prone. When called it
>   iterates over the DOM elements that
>   are part of the jQuery object. Each
>   time the callback runs, it is passed
>   the current loop iteration, beginning
>   from 0. More importantly, the callback
>   is fired in the context of the current
>   DOM element, so the keyword this
>   refers to the element.

[refer .each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

> The $.each() function is not the same
>   as .each(), which is used to iterate,
>   exclusively, over a jQuery object. The
>   $.each() function can be used to
>   iterate over any collection, whether
>   it is a map (JavaScript object) or an
>   array. In the case of an array, the
>   callback is passed an array index and
>   a corresponding array value each time.
>   (The value can also be accessed
>   through the this keyword.)

[$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: this is actually a different function from the one being asked about

Comment: @David - @cobbal is correct. The `.each()` method is a method that is part of every jQuery object used specifically to iterate over the matched set. `jQuery.each()` is a utility to iterate over any collection. The OP is asking specifically about `jQuery.each()`.

Comment: Ah ok. Every day is a school day!

Answer (score 4):

It is used to iterate exclusively, over a jQuery object. It can be used to iterate over any collection, see the [documentation for `jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 3):

The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each() function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.) The method returns its first argument, the object that was iterated.
1
2
3

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) {
alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```

This produces two messages:

0: 52
1: 97